# pop-up and css won't work on localhost or server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, popup, localhost

Please educate me about how am I going to connect the CSS to the server. I've followed two tutorials on youtube, one is using node.js and nodemailer. With this, I use a localhost to run my website but the CSS and js I made from the second tutorial (pop-up when button is clicked) won't work on the localhost but when I clicked the html file itself.

Is this because the tutorials are for different kinds of website? like static and dynamic?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my App</h1>
        <form>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Sender's Email: </label>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"> <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="classNum">To whom: R</label>
                <input type="number" id="classNum" placeholder="class#" min="1" max="31"> <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
                <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"> <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="text">Letter: </label> <br>
                <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="modal-button" data-modal-target="#modal">
            <div class="modal" id="modal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="title">Letter Sent!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Pressing this button will refresh the page.
                    <div><button data-close-button class="refresh-button">Send another letter</button></div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
        </form>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $('form').on('submit', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                const email = $('#email').val().trim();
                const subject = $('#subject').val().trim();
                const text = $('#text').val().trim();
                const classNum = $('#classNum').val().trim();

                const data = {
                    email,
                    subject,
                    text,
                    classNum
                };

                $.post('/email', data, function(){
                    console.log('Server received our data')
                });
            });;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the server.js

```js
const express = require('express');

const sendMail = require('./mail')

const log = console.log;
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const PORT = 8080;


app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
    const { subject, email, text, classNum} = req.body;
    console.log('Data: ', req.body);

    sendMail(email, subject, text, classNum, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Error'});
        }
        else{
            res.json({ message: 'Email sent!' });
        }
    });
   // res.json({ message: 'Message received!' })
});



app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => log('Server is starting on PORT: ', 8080));
```

And this one is for the pop-up, script.js

```js
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

var path = require('path') //from stackoverflow
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
        openModal(modal)
    })
})

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = button.closest('.modal')
        closeModal(modal)
    })
})


function openModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.add('active')
    overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closeModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
}
```

Please tell me if I need to include the CSS and the mail.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow users or browsers to get files from your server, you need to add them to your server-side code. For example, you've added a stylesheet reference to your `index.html`, so the browser will try to get that file (`/style.css`) from the server. You haven't put any reference to this on the server side, so the server will respond with 404 Not Found or another error.

In order to make the server respond to a request for "`/style.css`", you need to add the following to your server-side `index.js`:

```js
app.get("/style.css" /*name of file in index.html*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'style.css')); //CHANGE THIS TO THE NAME OF THE FILE ON THE SERVER
});
```

The same needs to happen for your browser script, `script.js`:

```
app.get("/script.js" /*name of file in index.html*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'script.js'));
});
```

`app.get` tells express to respond to a GET request to the first parameter: in the example, that's "`/style.css`". If you wanted to respond to a GET request to "`/foobar`", then you would write `app.get("/foobar", (req, res) => {/*SOME CODE HERE*/});` . The reason why it wasn't working was becuase when the browser tried to find `style.css` and `script.js`, the server didn't know what to do because you hadn't included `app.get` for those files, and therefore responded with an error.

---

This might be confusing due to the architecture of how this works. Look at this diagram:

```
==== HOW A WEBSITE SENDS A FILE ====

 ______                ____              ______
/ .  . \  GET /file   [____]   READ    /       |
|   j  |   ======>    [____]  ======>  | file  |
\__===_/   <======    [____]  <======  |       |
  user     RESPONSE   server           |_______|
```